# when i update password it does not save in bcrypted

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, node-modules

user.js

```
exports.updateUser = async (userId,userprops,userpic) => {
if (!userId) throw new Error ('Please Provide ID')
let userRecord = await userModel.updateUser(userId,userprops)

let pic = '';
if (userpic)pic = 'http://localhost:3000/'+userpic.path;

// Hashing Password
let hash = bcrypt.hashSync(userRecord[0].password, 10);

return{
    id: userRecord[0].id,
    firstName: userRecord[0].firstName,
    lastName: userRecord[0].lastName,
    pic: userRecord[0].pic =  pic ? pic : userRecord[0].pic,
    gender: userRecord[0].gender,
    dob: userRecord[0].dob,
    maritalStatus: userRecord[0].maritalStatus,
    nationality: userRecord[0].nationality,
    streetAddress: userRecord[0].streetAddress,
    city: userRecord[0].city,
    state: userRecord[0].state,
    postalCode: userRecord[0].postalCode,
    country: userRecord[0].country,
    phone: userRecord[0].phone,
    email: userRecord[0].email,
    jobTitle: userRecord[0].jobTitle,
    department: userRecord[0].department,
    dateOfJoining: userRecord[0].dateOfJoining,
    employeeStatus: userRecord[0].employeeStatus,
    kra: userRecord[0].kra,
    assignedSupervisor: userRecord[0].assignedSupervisor,
    assignedSubordinate: userRecord[0].assignedSubordinate,
    workExperience: userRecord[0].workExperience,
    skills: userRecord[0].skills,
    password: hash
}
}
```

When i save password it correctly saves password in bcrypted form. But when i update password it does not save in bcrypted form. when i hit in postman it return password in bcrypted form but in database it updates password in normal not bcrypted. Can  anyone help me, please?

Comment: I have no idea how this should work at all. There is no context to this one function. It looks like you are getting the password from the db and encrypt it to return it?
Shouldnt you get the password from request and encrypt it to save it in db?

Comment: You should encrypt the updated password in `userprops` before executing the query to update the userRecord. I believe it's because you're executing the query to update the user record with the raw `userprops` passed into the function that is causing the text password to replace the previously hashed password.